# Documentation contradictions about ReentrantReadWriteLock. Does eventually write lock has priority over read lock or not in fair mode?

Tags: java, concurrency, locking, readwritelock

From [ReentrantLock](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/ReentrantReadWriteLock.html) javadoc:

> **Fair mode**
>   When constructed as fair, threads contend for entry using an ***approximately*** 
>   arrival-order policy. When the currently held
>   lock is released either the longest-waiting single writer thread will
>   be assigned the write lock, or if there is a group of reader threads
>   waiting longer than all waiting writer threads, that group will be
>   assigned the read lock.
>
> A thread that tries to acquire a fair read
>   lock (non-reentrantly) will block if either the write lock is held, or
>   there is a waiting writer thread. The thread will not acquire the read
>   lock until after the oldest currently waiting writer thread has
>   acquired and released the write lock. Of course, if a waiting writer
>   abandons its wait, leaving one or more reader threads as the longest
>   waiters in the queue with the write lock free, then those readers will
>   be assigned the read lock.
>
> A thread that tries to acquire a fair write lock (non-reentrantly)
>   will block unless both the read lock and write lock are free (which
>   implies there are no waiting threads). (Note that the non-blocking
>   ReentrantReadWriteLock.ReadLock.tryLock() and
>   ReentrantReadWriteLock.WriteLock.tryLock() methods do not honor this
>   fair setting and will acquire the lock if it is possible, regardless
>   of waiting threads.)

Maybe it is problem with my English but I see contradictions at this decription:
From first paragrapgh I don't understand meaning of **approximately arrival-order policy**

1. from first paragraph I understand that lock acquire the oldest waiting thread. If oldest thread - read thread then it will be group of read threads which wait longer than the longest waiting write thread.
2. From second paragraph I understand that read lock will not acquire if write lock exists in wait-set.

Please clarify this contradiction.

Comment: @GhostCat I just want to wait more answers. Your answer is clear enough

Comment: The funny thing here: how much confusion comes out of that small piece of javadoc. You could consider turning your question into a bug report so that future users have an easier time when using these locks :-)

Comment: @GhostCat It is really strage thing. I believe that documentation should be more friendly

Comment: That is why I consider this worth an entry on some bugtracker.

Answer (score 3):

I don't see any contradictions in the description you quoted and I think you understand #1 correctly but #2 wrongly.

And by the way I think GhostCat description is wrong. There is nothing that sums up waiting time of different threads and compares them. The logic is actually much simpler.

My answer tends to be long but hopefully explanatory.

**Nonfair mode**

Let's start with "nonfair" mode lock first. "Nonfair" here means that

> A nonfair lock that is continuously contended may indefinitely postpone one or more reader or writer threads

So "fairness" here means that no thread could wait forever. "Nonfairness" means that if there is a constant flow of threads to acquire the read lock, and we have some thread (`W1`) that is waiting for the write lock, when new thread for read lock (`Rn`) comes it might get lock before the `W1` thread and so might in unlucky circumstances happen indefinitely. Note that even in "nonfair" mode `ReentrantReadWriteLock` *tries* to be reasonably fair it just doesn't *guaranties* fairness because, as the doc says, "fairness" is not free and the cost is lower throughput.

**Nonfair mode example**

So how real unfair behavior might happen. Assume there is a `W0` thread holding write lock and queue as of now is `R0` and `R1` waiting for the read lock, then `W1` waiting for the write lock, and also in the future there will be a huge stream of new thread coming for the read lock `Ri`. Also assume that thread `R1` thread has the lowest priority in the system and the OS never bumps up priority of threads even if they haven't worked for a very long time.

1. Write lock is held by `W0`, waiting queue is [`R0`, `R1`, `W1`]
2. `W0` releases the write lock, `R0` is woken up and acquires the read lock, now `R1` has low priority and is not woken up so can't acquire the read lock right now. Waiting queue is now [`R1`, `W1`]
3. `W1` is woken up but can't acquire the lock because of `R0`
4. Now while `R0` still holds the read lock, new reader thread `R2` arrives. As read lock is already acquired and the first thread in the waiting queue is a reader `R1`, `R2` acquires the read-lock immediately. The read lock is held by [`R0`, `R2`]. Waiting queue is still [`R1`, `W1`].
5. Now `R0` releases the lock but `W1` still can't acquire the write lock as it is held now by `R2`. Waiting queue is still [`R1`, `W1`].
6. Now while `R2` still holds the read lock, new reader thread `R3` arrives, acquires the read lock and the same story goes on and on.

What is important here is that:

- The first write thread `W1` is blocked from reading by a reading thread `R1` which is not woken up to acquire the lock because of low priority and/or pure bad luck.
- for newly arrived `Ri` thread to find out if there is any writing thread in the whole queue takes some time and effort and thus a simpler heuristic is applied (step #4): whether the very first waiting thread is write or read thread and the `R1` is reading one allowing fast acquisition. Note also that this logic at step #4 with checking the first thread in the queue is the attempt to be fair that I mentioned earlier and this is better than just naive implementation that has no such check.

**Fair mode**

So now back to fairness. As you might find at the [sources of FairSync](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8u40-b25/java/util/concurrent/locks/ReentrantReadWriteLock.java#689) inner class (I stripped minor details) :

```java
class FairSync extends Sync {
     final boolean writerShouldBlock() {
         return hasQueuedPredecessors();
     }
     final boolean readerShouldBlock() {
         return hasQueuedPredecessors();
     }
}
```

So literally yes, the difference between "fair" and "non-fair" is that in "fair" mode reader thread before acquiring the read-lock that it otherwise could acquire without breaking the ReadWriteLock contract additionally checks if there is any other thread in the queue before it. In this way `W1` thread from the previous example could not wait forever as `R2` and next thread would not acquire the read lock before it.

**Fair mode example**

Another attempt on the same example in fair mode:

1. Write lock is held by `W0`, waiting queue is [`R0`, `R1`, `W1`]
2. `W0` releases the write lock, `R0` acquires the read lock queue is [`R1`, `W1`]
3. `W1` is woken up but can't acquire the lock because of `R0`
4. `R2` arrives to the queue. Although the read lock is held by `R0` and `R2` seem to be able to acquire it as well, it doesn't do it because it sees `W1` ahead of itself. The read lock is held by `R0` and the queue is [`R1`, `W1`, `R2`]
5. Now both `W1` and `R2` can't acquire lock until `R1` is removed from the queue. Because of this finally `R1` is woken up gets the lock does the processing and releases the lock.
6. Finally `W1` acquires the write lock and `R2`, `R3` and others are still in the queue waiting.

In terms of this example `R0` and `R1` form a "group" but `R2` doesn't belong to that "group" because it is after `W1` in the queue.

**Summary**

So first paragraph describes is what happens when a lock is released and the strategy is simple: the first waiting thread acquires the lock. If the first waiting thread happens to be read-thread, then all other read threads in the queue ***before*** the first writing thread acquire the read lock. All such read threads are called "group". Note that this doesn't mean all read threads waiting for the lock!

Second paragraph describes what happens when a new read-thread arrives and tries to acquire lock and behavior here is actually consistent with first paragraph: if there is a waiting write-thread in the queue before the current thread, it will not acquire the lock the same way it would not acquire the lock if it was added to the queue before lock was released and rules from paragraph #1 would apply.
Hope this helps.

Comment: @gstackoverflow, I don't understand what you refer to as "that second paragraph about **non-fair** mode". In the spec you linked there is only one paragraph of two sentences. Could you be more specific? As for the "queue in the non-fair mode", it is a tradeoff that the library designers made: they decided that small performance degradation because of a queue with simple logic to check is a small price to pay for much better fairness even in "non-fair" mode so that the "non-fair" mode lock might be reasonably safe default choice for most of the users (see what default constructor does).

Comment: Sorry, it was my mistake

Comment: @gstackoverflow, So is everything clear for you now or do you have more questions?

Comment: Now  your answer is clear for. I am await community reaction

Comment: Out of curiosity: did you study the implementation, or how did you develop your explanation? And although you dared to correct me: p1 for your excellent input.

Comment: @GhostCat, did I know it beforehand in those details? No. But the question seemed interesting and your answer seemed "literally unbelievable" i.e. I didn't believe it really works that way. So yes, I opened the code and dug up some real details. If you are interested, then actually the surprising part for me was an attempt to make "non-fair" mode significantly more fair.

Answer (score 2):

Here, quoting from your quote:

*or if there is a **group** of reader threads*

In other words: a writer wins over a **single** reader; but when a group of readers wants the lock, those get the lock.

Regarding the question: "and what does *group* actually mean" ... that would be an implementation detail, only available by looking into the [source code](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8u40-b25/java/util/concurrent/locks/ReentrantReadWriteLock.java#ReentrantReadWriteLock).

Comment: from which size starts group?

Answer (score 1):

The fair mode policy is only "approximately arrival-order" because threads waiting to acquire a read-lock are batched, and a thread that arrived later to acquire a read lock might get the lock earlier than another thread from the same batch trying to acquire a read lock, due to OS scheduling.

A "group of reader threads" can be just one thread.

There is no contradiction in the spec, but it might not be as clear as it could be.

Suppose thread A holds a write lock on the mutex.

Thread B arrives and tries to get a write lock.
Then thread C arrives and tries to get a read lock. Then thread D arrives and tries to get a read lock. Then thread E arrives and tries to get a write lock. Then thread F arrives and tries to get a read lock.

Now thread A unlocks the mutex. The fair mode policy implies that thread B will get the lock: it has been waiting longest.

When thread B releases the lock, threads C and D will get the read lock, but not thread F. C and D are a "group of reader threads waiting longer than all waiting writer threads". Thread F is still blocked, because it has been waiting less long than thread E, which is a writer thread.

If thread E then abandons the wait (e.g. it times out), then thread F is now the oldest waiting thread, and the current lock is a read lock, so thread F can acquire the lock before threads C and D release theirs.

If thread G now tries to acquire the write lock, it will block until all of threads C, D and F have released their read locks.

If thread H now tries to acquire a read lock, it will block: there is a waiting writer thread.

If thread I now tries to acquire a writer lock, it will block: there is a queue of waiting threads.

Now, C, D and F release their locks, so thread G (the longest waiting thread) acquires the writer lock.

Thread G releases the lock, and thread H acquires the lock: it is a group of one reader thread, that has been waiting longer than any waiting writer.

Finally, when thread H releases the lock, thread I can acquire it.